# Is there a way to compare two objects of a different type in C#

Tags: c#, compare

I've seen a few similar threads on this but none that answered my problem and I'm struggling enough to have to ask now.

I have two objects, one named Customer and another which is a data transfer object called customerDto.

Customer:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    [DataMember] 
    public int Id { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string Title { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string FirstName { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string Middle { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string LastName { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string Email { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string HomePhone { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string MobilePhone { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string AddressLine1 { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string AddressLine2 { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public string PostCode { get;  set;}
    [DataMember] 
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get;  set;}
    [DataMember][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] 
    public string FullName { get; private set;}
  }

public partial class Customer
{
    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryDetail> DeliveryDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerDto:

```
public class CustomerDto : ICloneable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I need to compare the properties they share but I don't want to write a multi-line if statement because that is messy. Is there a way this can be done?

I only need to see if there is a difference in any of the properties they share. If one is different then we can progress and update the customer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make a subclass of it, and do the comparison at that element?

Comment: You could also use reflection to compare fields with same name, but i think it's probably better subclassing or making an interface

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for here is a foreach loop that uses reflection.

```
Customer customer; // assume its initialized
CustomerDto custDTO; 
var recordsAreDifferent = false;
foreach (var prop in custDTO.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  PropertyInfo customerProperty = customer.GetType().GetProperty(prop.name);
  if(customerProperty == null) {continue;}
 if(!prop.GetValue(custDTO, null).Equals(customerProperty.GetValue(customer,    null)) {
     recordsAreDifferent = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a cleaner addition, I would have `Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> differences` where I would have the key as the field and the two strings as the current and compared

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a generic method that uses reflection:

```
public static bool CompareMatchingProperties<TLeft,TRight>(TLeft lhs, TRight rhs) {
    var allLeft = typeof(TLeft).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
    var allRight = typeof(TRight).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
    foreach (var name in allLeft.Keys.Intersect(allRight.Keys)) {
        if (!object.Equals(allLeft[name].GetValue(lhs), allRight[name].GetValue(rhs))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The idea is to get all public properties from types on both sides (see `allLeft` and `allRight` dictionaries) construct an intersection of their names (`allLeft.Keys.Intersect(allRight.Keys)` in the loop), obtain property values from each object being compared (`allLeft[name].GetValue(lhs)` and `allRight[name].GetValue(rhs)`) and compare them using `object.Equals`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/VIxJ7d)

One thing to keep in mind with any approach of this kind is that the result of comparing two objects that do not have any properties in common would return `true`. You can work around that by requiring at least one pair of properties to match.

Comment: I would also consider creating a `TryCompare...` which returns a explanatory dictionary on what was different... see comment to other answer

Answer (score 1):

You may consider Customer class implementing IComparable interface and implementing CompareTo(Object obj) method.

Or

Implement [IEquatable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)

Comment: except he doesnt want to have to manually write out all of the checks for the different properties.

Comment: Dealing with runtime errors because something happens during reflection is much more difficult than writing a (very fast, but verbose) IComparable implementation.

Comment: that is way I said You may consider - let him decide.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a specific method like this:

```
    public bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer, CustomerDto dto)
    {
        //Get properties from both objects
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] customerProperties = customer.GetType().GetProperties();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] dtoProperties = dto.GetType().GetProperties();

        //Get properties that have the same name on both objects
        var propertiesToCompare = from customerProp in customerProperties 
                                  join dtoProp in dtoProperties 
                                  on customerProp.Name equals dtoProp.Name
                                  select customerProp;

        foreach (var property in propertiesToCompare)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(customer, null) != property.GetValue(dto, null))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You get all the properties from both your objects then you check if any of the properties they share have different values. If they do, the method returns true. If not, it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, CustomerDto to is entity of DB,Customer is a contract for clients. What about converting Customer type to CustomerDto and compare two objects of CustomerDto?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare 2 objects and you are working in C#, i think a good way to do this is with operators overloads. To do this you way consider a few points:

- All the operator overloads are static methods
- You have unary operators and binary operators.
- To overload a comparator operator (<<, >>, ==, !=, >, <, >=, <=) You have to overload the opposing operator. (for example if you ovearload ">" also have to overload "<")
- You have to declare it in some of the classes of the objects involved.

The sintaxis is some like this.

```
    public static ReturnValue operator+(Object a, Object b)
    {
       // Comparison logic
       return value;

    }
```

For your particular problem you should do something like this:

```
public static Boolean operator==(Customer cust, CustomerDto custDto)
{
    //Here you code a for or foreach o whatever you want to compare
    //cust with custDto and return true is you found a difference or false
    //if there are no differences

    return booleanValue;
}
```

Then ovearload the != operator. To reuse code you can recall the other comparator:

```
public static Boolean operator!=(Customer cust, CustomerDto custDto)
    {  
        return !(cust == custDto);
    }
```

So in your code you can check if there is a difference between one Customer object and one CustomerDto object with something like this:

```
if (customerObject == customerDtoObject)
{
   //Whatever you want
}
```

Hope this will help you.